# How to not print/output anything from a curly bracket operation within the HTML of a Svelte app

Tags: svelte

There may come a time when you want to perform an operation directly to a variable within if statements or each loops of your Svelte component HTML. In this example we have a variable **jVar** within an HTML 'each' loop and we want to change to the value of jVar to whatever is returned from a call to an 'updateJ' function.

```
<blockquote style="border: 2px solid red;padding:10px;">
    {#each cats as { id, name, isCute }, i}
        {( jVar = updateJ(isCute) )}
        <div><h2>{i + 1}: {name} is {#if !jVar}<em style="color:red;">NOT!!!</em>{/if} cute</h2>
        </div>
    {/each}
</blockquote>
```

The only problem is that we do not want the following statement to print/output anything to the HTML.

```
{( jVar = updateJ(isCute) )}
```

The way it is written the value of jVar will be printed to the HTML. More details on this problem and answer can be found here:
https://svelte.dev/repl/095b7f2439dc42d380741350ea11b20f?version=3.22.3

Answer (score 1):

See the following Svelte REPL app for a working example:
https://svelte.dev/repl/095b7f2439dc42d380741350ea11b20f?version=3.22.3

Basically what you need to do is modify the statement to look something like this:

```
{returnNada ( jVar = updateJ(isCute) )}
```

...where **returnNada** is a simple function (that we add within our script tags) that does nothing but return an empty string to the HTML output but still allow the jVar variable to be updated.

Comment: While this works, I would say it's an anti-pattern. If the inner part of your `#each` loop requires logic, consider moving it into a component of its own instead, it will make your code more readable and your intentions clearer.

Comment: Thomas is right. Don't do this! You're actually setting `j` to be a *global*, which is brittle and error-prone. In this case you can just do `{#if !updateJ(isCute)}` instead.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. In the actual code where I use this example `jVar` is a Svelte store object, which looks like `storeFE.formElements[fIndex].fValue` to be exact; not a simple string variable. I am dynamically building a form based on a JSON config and my `storeFE` object holds the form state (all of the form element configurations and response state as a user fills out the form). With that said, if `jVar` is a Svelte store object, is this code changing the scope of jVar?

Comment: While the example given in the Q probably doesn't need the solution, I **think** I do ( i want to split my iterated value and put some formatting inamongst it). Has a more official and supported way to suppres return value output come along in the last 3 years?