# Svelte: How to not display or hide JS output within an {#each} statement?

Tags: javascript, html, svelte

Is there a way to not display or hide JS output within an {#each} statement?

For example, I perform a string split within an {#each} statement and just want to display the result of the 2nd statement not the 1st in the HTML.

{array = string.split(".")} {array[0]}

[With reference to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61925402/how-to-not-print-output-anything-from-a-curly-bracket-operation-within-the-html)

Comment: So why are you not doing `string.split(".")[0]`

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know you could chain the split method like that.